# How do I get an SRI (subresource integrity) hash for aspnetcdn.com?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to upgrade the jQuery and [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) version on a ASP.NET Core project.

Initially, Visual Studio created this by default in the _layout.cshtml file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
        asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
        integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
```

Where can I get the integrity attribute's values for new versions?

Answer (score 8):

I've been using https://www.srihash.org/, but you can google "SRI Hash Generator" if that site is ever down.